# Delete image from sql database

Tags: php, html, css, image

I have form for uploading profile images, but I need to add option to remove profile images. I'm total newbie so please help, here's the code : Database connection is added at top, upload form is working and avatar image path in database is ( suggestions/avatar )

```
<input name=newimage type=submit value='Change avatar' class=textbox>
<input name=delimage type=submit value='Remove Avatar' class=textbox>

$getav = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM suggestions WHERE id = '$ida'");
$getavarray = mysql_fetch_array($getav);
$getav = $getavarray['avatar'];


if($getav){$avatar = "avatars/$getav";}else{$avatar = "Untitled-1.png";}

if(isset($_POST['newimage'])){
//die(' ');
//define a maxim size for the uploaded images in Kb
 define ("MAX_SIZE","1000000"); 

//This function reads the extension of the file. It is used to determine if the file  is an image by checking the extension.
 function getExtension($str) {
         $i = strrpos($str,".");
         if (!$i) { return ""; }
         $l = strlen($str) - $i;
         $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
         return $ext;
 }

//This variable is used as a flag. The value is initialized with 0 (meaning no error  found)  
//and it will be changed to 1 if an errro occures.  
//If the error occures the file will not be uploaded.
 $errors=0;
//checks if the form has been submitted



    //reads the name of the file the user submitted for uploading
    $image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
    //if it is not empty
    if ($image) 
    {
    //get the original name of the file from the clients machine
        $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
    //get the extension of the file in a lower case format
        $extension = getExtension($filename);
        $extension = strtolower($extension);
    //if it is not a known extension, we will suppose it is an error and will not  upload the file,  
    //otherwise we will do more tests
 if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) 
        {
        //print error message
            die('<font color=white face=verdana size=1>Error with the file type. Only JPEG, PNG, GIF and JPG formats allowed.</font>');
            $errors=1;
        }
        else
        {
//get the size of the image in bytes
 //$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] is the temporary filename of the file
 //in which the uploaded file was stored on the server
 $size=filesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

//compare the size with the maxim size we defined and print error if bigger
if ($size > MAX_SIZE*10024)
{
    die('<font color=white face=verdana size=1>Image size must be 10000kb or less.</font>');
    $errors=1;
}

//we will give an unique name, for example the time in unix time format
$image_name=$ida.'.'.$extension;
//the new name will be containing the full path where will be stored (images folder)
$newname="avatars/".$image_name;
//we verify if the image has been uploaded, and print error instead



$ra = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM suggestions WHERE id= '$ida'");
$ras = mysql_fetch_array($ra);
$rasface = $ras['avatar'];

$fileaa = "avatars/".$rasface;

if($rasface){
unlink($fileaa); }


$copied = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $newname);
mysql_query("UPDATE suggestions SET avatar = '$image_name' WHERE id = '$ida'");
if (!$copied) 
{
    die('<font color=white face=verdana size=1>Error please try again.</font>');
    $errors=1;
}
else {echo "<font color=white face=verdana size=1>Avatar image changed successfully!</font>";}


}}}
```

I allready added Delete button : , but I don't have idea how to link it to delete avatar.

Comment: if you can `select` and `update`, surely you should also know about `delete` queries...

Comment: I know, but whatever I try it's not working.

Comment: Please describe what "isn't working". Additionally, please don't use the font tag. Every time you do, Time Berners Lee kills a kitten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place a checkbox on the site;

```
<input name="remove" type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

Then when the form is submitted check if the checkbox is ticked;

```
// Was the checkbox ticked to mark the deleting of the image?
if(isset($_POST['remove']) && $_POST['remove'] == 1)
{
    // Do a query to get the image's full path - this is unknown to me,
    // but you should be able to code this using your database's fields
    unlink($path); // This will delete the file from the server

    // Then delete the corresponding row in the database
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM suggestions WHERE id = 'YOUR_ID_HERE'");

}
```